# Copy grep output from vim editor

Tags: vim

Assume you have some text file (e.g. a log file) and you open
it in a `vim` editor and hit the command

```
:g/aaa
```

It will output a result in which you can move with `j` and `k` keys
and when you move to the bottom a green sentence
`Press ENTER or type command to continue` will appear.

I understand it somehow, that I can use some commands with the result,
but don't know how to find what I can do with it.

One action I'd like to do, is to save the lines to the new file.

Of course you could use a command

```
$ grep aaa file.txt > new_file.txt
```

but is it possible from the `vim` editor directly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible to do this through a multi-step process.

Within `vim`:

```
:redir > new_file.txt
:g/aaa
:redir END
```

See `:help redir` from within `vim`.

The `:redir` command can also append to an existing file by modifying the first command.

```
:redir >> new_file.txt
```

Comment: Or one could use `:vimgrep` and `:grep` with `:copen`.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is to reverse the `:g` into `:v` and do `:v/pattern/d`, then copy the resulting text into a register with `1GVG"ry` and finally undo the `:v` with `u`. Now the matched lines are safely in register `r`.